# Pass DBRef in mongo query while fetching a document using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java, dbref

```
 db.collectionB.findOne()
 {
    "_id" : NumberLong(24),
    "class" : "Top",
    "type" : DBRef("collectionA", NumberLong(47))
 }
db.collectionA.findOne()
{
   "_id" : NumberLong(47),
   "name" : "John",
   "position" : 2 
}
```

QUERY to be formed : db.collectionB.find({type: DBRef("collectionA", NumberLong(47))});

There are a number of documents in collection A & collectionB. I want to search the documents where "type" in collectionB is referring to document where "_id" is NumberLong(47) in collectionA.

```
BasicDBObject query =   new BasicDBObject("name","John");
DBObject db_object = findOne("collectionA",query);
DBRef myDbRef = new DBRef(db,"collectionB",db_object); 
DBObject doc = myDbRef.fetch(); 
System.out.println(doc);
```

It gives the output null. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [3-argument constructor of DBRef](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html#DBRef%28com.mongodb.DB,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) takes the following arguments:

- Database
- Namespace
- ID

Your second argument isn't a namespace, it is just the collection. It should be a string `"yourDatabaseName.collectionB"`.

Your third argument isn't just an ID, it's a complete object. That way the DBRef points to a document where the value of the field `_id` *is a complete copy* of the document you pass. Such a document doesn't exist, so fetching the DBRef returns null.

To create a valid DBRef you only pass the value of `_id` to the constructor of `DBRef`.

But when I understood your requirement "I want to search the documents where "type" in collectionB is referring to document where "_id" is NumberLong(47) in collectionA." correctly, you don't even have to query collectionA. DBRef's are just transparent sub-objects with this structure: `{ "$ref" : <value>, "$id" : <value>, "$db" : <value> }`. So you should be able to find the desired documents with:

```
db.collectionB.find("type.$id": 47);
```

This assumes that all the dbref's under `type` reference the same collection and database. When that's not the case, you need to include these in your query to avoid results referencing another collection:

```
db.collectionB.find("type.$id": 47, "type.$ref": "collectionA", "type.$db": <database name>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It was really helpful. One more confusion, while passing arguments to DBRef constructor, which collection is used-the collection which is referring (collectionB) or the collection being referenced (collectionA)

Comment: DBRef myDbRef = new DBRef(db,"mydbname.collectionA",db_object.get("_id"));  Is this ok?

Comment: @SET the namespace you pass to the DBRef constructor is of course the one the DBRef should point to.